# clear textbox on submit button without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the jquery and the two code lines one for the text box and the other for the submit button but i just cant get them to link. I have tried a few different ways suggested on here but i cannot get the submit button to link to the text box and clear it. All help greatly appreciated

`$j` is set as `noConflict()`

```js
$j('.submit').keypress(function(){
    $j('.comment').val('');
});
```

```html
<textarea name="name" rows="5" class="fullinput" id="comment"></textarea> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add to List" class="add" />
```

UPDATE -  So i realised that i was using the incorrect selectors the correct code should have been.

```
$j('#submit').click(function(event){
  $j('#comment').val('');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This along with the answers below resolved this issue.

Comment: you probably need `.click()`.

Comment: Is this wrapped in a `form`? What are you submitting? Also, the `input` field should be a `button`

Comment: user $ insted of $j

Comment: the j is in the for non conflict jquery

Comment: You can use `$("form")[0].reset()` to clearing all inputs.

Comment: You are using `$j('.comment').val('');` but your textarea has no comment class but it has comment id...so try with `$j('#comment').val('');` and do the same for the input button wich has id button, no class button

Comment: use $("#submit) insted of $(".submit).

Comment: Can you tell what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: resolved now but thank you :)

Comment: up vote for listening to feedback and reformatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$j('#submit').click(function(event){
    $j('#comment').val('');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

By clicking on a "submit" input, the user is invoking a postback. Therefore you need to use the built-in javascript event to prevent the postback from happening using the .preventDefault() method.

Comment: unfortunatley not it submits the form but leaves the previous data in

Comment: Try it with `$(` instead of `$j(` - I'm not convinced that is the correct way to invoke jQuery, unless you have an unusual setup

Comment: There are no classes. You should try `#submit` and `#comment` instead of `.submit` and `.comment`.

Comment: you didn't specify anything about a database in your question. You asked how to clear the field when the button's clicked. This is the answer. If you want to save it somewhere else you should capture the value elsewhere (e.g. in a variable) before you clear it. Or you should send to the database before you clear the field. Are you sending data to the database via ajax?

Comment: apologies its submitted via a function $update_stages through mysqli

Comment: @troggy69 that's PHP on the server side. How's it submitted from the client? If you've included all my code it should no longer be doing a full postback, so there must be some other method?

Comment: My Mistake its is added via jquery i had just added it in the wrong place which was overwriting the original query hence the blank data input all sorted now many thanks

Comment: @troggy69 no problem, happy to help